# Android: get all JSON values froma a certain category

Tags: java, json

I would like to ask you for help concerning parsing JSON String.

I have a JSON string which can be seen here: http://www.skbf-csre.ch/apps/iphone/rss/?displayFormat=JSON&language=french&function=newsList

And I would like to get for example all the titles where the category is "Document de discussion". I don't know how to do it.

I have tryed like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayFrench.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonArrayFrench.getJSONArray(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            if(jsonObject.getString("category").equals("Document de discussion"))
                subnewsFrench.add(jsonObject.getString("title"));
        }
```

But I am getting only the first, and not the 3 titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, here is the working example.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayFrench.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonArrayFrench.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j=0; j < innerJsonArray.length(); j++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                if(jsonObject.getString("category").equals(category))
                    subnewsFrench.add(jsonObject.getString("title"));
            }   
}
```

If this can help you, please enjoy.